# Unable to load Type from Universal Assembly in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-container, moq, win-universal-app

I have a series of Universal Portable Class Libraries that I am using in a project. All of the PCL's target .NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows phone 8, iOS and Android. The app is broken up into a couple of shared projects, repository projects and services projects.

I then added a standard Unit Test project to the solution. The project targets the required shared libraries along with the one Repository library I want to test. When I run the test, I receive a System.TypeLoadException: Could not load Type 'BasicTaskRepository' from assembly.

I have several assemblies that are Universal PCL's with the same targets. I can write a unit test for any other assembly and they work and pass. For some reason, when I target the `Duty.Repositories.Tasks` assembly for unit testing, I get the exception.

My repository interface and implementation.

```
namespace Duty.Repositories.Shared
{
    public interface ITaskRepository
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<BasicTask>> GetTasks();
        Task<BasicTask> GetTask(Guid taskId);
        Task<BasicTask> SaveTask(BasicTask task);
        Task DeleteTask(BasicTask task);
        Task DeleteTask(Guid taskId);
    }
}

namespace Duty.Repositories.Tasks
{
    public class BasicTaskRepository : ITaskRepository
    {
        private ITaskService service;

        public BasicTaskRepository(ITaskService service)
        {
            this.service = service;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<BasicTask>> GetTasks()
        {
            IEnumerable<BasicTask> tasks = await this.service.GetTasks();

            return tasks;
        }

        public async Task<BasicTask> GetTask(Guid taskId)
        {
            BasicTask task = await this.service.GetTask(taskId);
            return task;
        }
    }
}
```

Next is my ITaskService interface and implementation.

```
namespace Duty.Services.Shared
{
    public interface ITaskService
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<BasicTask>> GetTasks();
        Task<BasicTask> GetTask(Guid taskId);
        Task<BasicTask> SaveTask(BasicTask task);
        Task DeleteTask(BasicTask task);
        Task DeleteTask(Guid taskId);
    }
}

namespace Duty.Services.ParseCloud
{
    public class TaskService : ITaskService
    {
        public TaskService()
        {
            ParseClient.Initialize("SomeKey", "AnotherKey");
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<BasicTask>> GetTasks()
        {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery(typeof(BasicTask).Name);
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> parseObjects = await query.FindAsync();

            // Convert the parse objects returned from the cloud into our local model representation.
            // We do this in order order to maintain support for the model across multiple cloud services
            // instead of restricting ourselves to the entire app using ParseCloud only.
            return parseObjects.Select(po => this.ConvertParseObjectToDutyTask(po));
        }

        public async Task<BasicTask> GetTask(Guid taskId)
        {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery(typeof(BasicTask).Name)
                .WhereEqualTo("ObjectId", taskId.ToString());
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> parseObjects = await query.FindAsync();

            return parseObjects.Select(po => this.ConvertParseObjectToDutyTask(po)).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        private BasicTask ConvertParseObjectToDutyTask(ParseObject parseObject)
        {
            Guid taskId = Guid.Empty;
            Guid.TryParse(parseObject.ObjectId, out taskId);

            return new BasicTask
            {
                TaskId = taskId,
                Title = parseObject["Title"].ToString(),
                IsCompleted = (bool)parseObject["IsCompleted"],
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my two unit tests. The Unit tests accessing the repository fails with the aforementioned exception while the one accessing the service directly passes every-time.

```
public class BasicTaskRepositoryTests
{
    private ITaskService taskService;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var basicTasks = new List<BasicTask>()
        {
            new BasicTask { Title = "Test Title 1", TaskId = Guid.Empty },
            new BasicTask { Title = "Test Title 2", TaskId = Guid.Empty, },
        };

        var serviceMock = new Mock<ITaskService>();

        // Set up our mock service object.
        serviceMock.Setup(service => service.GetTasks()).ReturnsAsync(basicTasks);
        serviceMock.Setup(service => service.GetTask(It.IsAny<Guid>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(basicTasks.FirstOrDefault());
        serviceMock.Setup(service => service.SaveTask(It.IsAny<BasicTask>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(basicTasks.FirstOrDefault());
        serviceMock.Setup(service => service.DeleteTask(It.IsAny<BasicTask>()))
            .Returns<BasicTask>(null);

        this.taskService = serviceMock.Object;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TaskRepository_GetBasicTasks_HasTasks()
    {
        // Arrange
        var taskRepository = new Duty.Repositories.Tasks.BasicTaskRepository(taskService);

        // Act
        IEnumerable<BasicTask> tasks = await taskRepository.GetTasks();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual<int>(2, tasks.Count());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TaskService_GetBasicTasks_HasTasks()
    {
        // Arrange
        var serviceRepo = new Services.ParseCloud.TaskService();

        // Act
        IEnumerable<BasicTask> tasks = await serviceRepo.GetTasks();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(2, tasks.Count());
    }
}
```

Again, all of my libraries are PCL targetting .NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1, iOS and Android. There are no target differences between the Service PCL and the Repository PCL. The Unit Test Project is a standard Unit Test (non-Windows Universal) but I have a hard time finding that to be the problem since the Service test references the Universal PCL without a hitch.

I have removed the Repositories project from the solution, re-built and re-ran the tests (as suggested [in similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388903/unit-testing-error-unable-to-get-type-error-could-not-load-type-from-ass)) and then added the project back; that did not fix the issue.

I deleted the entire project and re-created it fresh, and still the same issue. I removed the reference to Moq and passed the Service into the Repository constructor directly, with the exact same result. It can't find the assembly.

This is my attempt to remove Moq from the equation.

```
    public void Setup()
    {
        var basicTasks = new List<BasicTask>()
        {
            new BasicTask { Title = "Test Title 1", TaskId = Guid.Empty },
            new BasicTask { Title = "Test Title 2", TaskId = Guid.Empty, },
        };
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TaskRepository_GetBasicTasks_HasTasks()
    {
        // Arrange
        var taskRepository = new Duty.Repositories.Tasks.BasicTaskRepository(
            new Duty.Services.ParseCloud.TaskService());

        // Act
        IEnumerable<BasicTask> tasks = await taskRepository.GetTasks();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual<int>(2, tasks.Count());
    }
```

Can anyone offer any help on this? I'm at a total loss.

```
Test Name:  TaskRepository_GetBasicTasks_HasTasks
Test FullName:  Duty.UnitTests.Repositories.Tasks.BasicTaskRepositoryTests.TaskRepository_GetBasicTasks_HasTasks
Test Source:    c:\Source\Workspaces\sullinger.visualstudio.com\Duty\Main\App\DutyApp\Duty.UnitTests\Duty.Repositories\Duty.Repositories.Tasks\BasicTaskRepositoryTests.cs : line 42
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.0295863

Result Message: 
Test method Duty.UnitTests.Repositories.Tasks.BasicTaskRepositoryTests.TaskRepository_GetBasicTasks_HasTasks threw exception: 
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Duty.Repositories.Tasks.BasicTaskRepository' from assembly 'Duty.Repositories.Tasks, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Result StackTrace:  
at Duty.UnitTests.Repositories.Tasks.BasicTaskRepositoryTests.<TaskRepository_GetBasicTasks_HasTasks>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Duty.UnitTests.Repositories.Tasks.BasicTaskRepositoryTests.TaskRepository_GetBasicTasks_HasTasks()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wild guess - is your test project targeting the correct .NET framework?

Comment: Thanks for the response George, the problem was that my unit test and library shared the same project name by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. My project structure is laid out like the following

```
Solution
  |___Repositories
  |_______Duty.Repositories.Tasks
  |___Tests
  |______Repositories
  |___________Duty.Repositories.Tasks
```

I had my unit test project named the same as my repositories project. As soon as I renamed my unit test project to Duty.Repositories.TasksTests (like it should have been anyway) it resolved my problem.